# Fails to move further from Login page, [django-otp]

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, two-factor-authentication, one-time-password

**Problem:**

I am redirecting back to Login page with the following error message after providing username and password

"Please enter a correct email and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive."

**Detail:**

I have followed the documentation of [Django Two-Factor Authentication](http://django-two-factor-auth.readthedocs.org/en/1.0.0/index.html). I must missed something in configurations but don't know exactly. Bellow are the detail from my code.

***settings.py***

```
# in middle ware classes
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django_otp.middleware.OTPMiddleware',
    ...

# in installed apps
    ...
    'django_otp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_totp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_hotp',
    'django_otp.plugins.otp_static',
    'two_factor',
    'otp_yubikey',
    ...

LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('two_factor:login')

TWO_FACTOR_PATCH_ADMIN = True
TWO_FACTOR_CALL_GATEWAY = 'two_factor.gateways.fake.fake'
TWO_FACTOR_SMS_GATEWAY = 'two_factor.gateways.fake.Fake'
TWO_FACTOR_QR_FACTORY = 'qrcode.image.pil.PilImage'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('two_factor:profile')
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('myapp.backends.EmailAuthBackend',)
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
OTP_LOGIN_URL = LOGIN_URL
```

Logger is also looking fine

***urls.py***

```
url(r'', include(tf_urls + tf_twilio_urls, 'two_factor')),
```

and in ***views.py***

```
@otp_required()
def home(request):
    # some logic with HTTP response
```

***NOTE:*** I have custom user models in my app and registered them in admin.py in addition to this question i am pasting that file too to be clear.

***admin.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm, UserCreationForm
from apps.users.models import User
from django import forms


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User


class MyUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username']
        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username
        raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])


class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    add_form = MyUserCreationForm
    # fieldsets = UserAdmin.fieldsets + (
    #     (None, {'fields': ('extra_field1', 'extra_field2',)}),
    # )

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Please suggest where i am going wrong. And let me know if I am not much clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my point is: since you use inheriting from User model, you need to use AUTH_USER_MODEL as an auth route. That means, you already have a two auth ways. Maybe you should check two tables: otp_device and auth_users. I mean when you put your log/pass in form, it is checking with auth_users table. But in device table you don't have a request user. So, otp auth system can't match with None record and redirect you on login page.

If I had a similar situation, I decided to try two solutions:

1. Create a signal to sync users and device table;
2. Use old version of user customization (OneToOneField with User model).

I think it's too complicated way for auth: three app (two_factor, otp and default auth) are using the similar auth technology.

Comment: Great.... this is also the way to use auth user having OneToOneField of my custom user. I will ask some questions if needed. I appreciates your interest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in documentation: "Be sure to remove any other login routes, otherwise the two-factor authentication might be circumvented. The admin interface should be automatically patched to use the new login method."

Try to figure out a reason to use AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

Comment: thanks for your time. LOGIN_URL is routed to two-factor as per the documentation. There is not any other login rout.

I have custom user models and not using django-auth. That is why i have this

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

I know this is not a good idea but i am bound to use custom models.

Comment: Ok, I understood. Could you please tell your django version and how you created a custom user model?

Comment: Yes, Django version is 1.5.1. User models are inherited from AbstractBaseUser. I have defined custom manager for this model as well. admin.py is in question detail. AUTH_USER_MODEL is also defined in settings.py. Please let me know if you need any thing else